# Does a high-velocity ion being neutralized by an electron emit Brehmsstrahlung radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation, fusion

I'm curious about a point of the physics of [Polywell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polywell) electrostatic confinement fusion devices. One of the key  claims made in the design is that by confining some "low temperature" electrons to a region in the center of the device using a magnetic field, you can then create a strong electric field that will accelerate ions to "high temperature" (high velocity). This seems true, at least in the sense that the ions do indeed reach high enough velocities to interact and fuse, albeit only occasionally.

However, for net energy production, a Polywell device needs to produce more fusion energy than it loses. One main source of loss is electron conduction and confinement, but my question isn't about that. Another main unproven point is whether or not a significant amount of energy will be carried away from the plasma through x-ray Brehmsstrahlung radiation resulting from the non-thermal high-temp ions heating up the electrons to a temperature similar to the incoming ions.

To just understand a small part of this, I would like to learn how to calculate the first step. The question is:

What sort of radiative energy loss occurs when an ion strikes a low-temperature Maxwellian electron cloud, interacts with some electrons, and ends up neutralized and moving through the center of the cloud?

Symmetry seems to cry out to me, but I'm not a subtle physicist. If the (non-gravitational?) acceleration of charged particles causes radiation to be emitted according to the [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula), then when an accelerated high-speed ion strikes a low-temp cloud of electrons, wouldn't the situation be very similar to an accelerated electron striking a fixed target, and thus significant radiation could be expected to be emitted? Or, is there another equation that would describe how the energy of the ion might be spread out amongst the electrons it passes near?

Comment: A high velocity ion is not going to be neutralized in the scattering process (or extremely rarely). Some energy will be transferred to the electrons, which will then scatter amongst themselves. Some excitation of the ion's remaining electrons may be expected, possibly leading to emission from the ion.

Comment: when it is neutralized it will emit an appropriate energy photon to the level where the electron was caught.

Comment: @JonCuster I am under the impression that the cross section for electric interaction is much larger than the odds of one ion striking another ion, particularly since there are so many electrons in the cloud relative to ions. Wouldn't ion-electron interaction be the dominant interaction, causing scattering and kinetic energy loss for the ions?